# IntelliJ IDEA does not find candidates for kotlinOptions property but project works fine

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I always create Kotlin projects with Gradle: File -> New -> Project -> Gradle -> Kotlin/JVM.
The project works fine, however, IntelliJ IDEA highlights this part of the code:
[build.gradle false warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byc8L.png)

**Is there a way to remove this warning?**

This is the entire build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "$kotlinVersion"
}

group "com.alelad"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {}

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "13"
            allWarningsAsErrors = true
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "13"
            allWarningsAsErrors = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you actually need multiple projects? Notice you're applying the kotlin plugin twice, once in the top of the file, then again in `allProjects`.

Comment: If you have a single-module project, remove the allProjects block and move the declarations, excluding the `apply plugin` ones, to the top-level. That should stop that warning.

Comment: Also, you're missing dependencies on the kotlin stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove compileKotlin and compileTestKotlin all together. They are deprecated now and your project should work just fine without them. That's what I'm doing and everything works great in all my projects.